# Long list of spurious albums in iOS photo picker

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

I've first noticed it with Concur app on iPhone and now see the same behavior with the fashionable BlueSky app, where it's adding a photo much worse.  When you tap "add photo" icon, you are going to a list of albums.  It takes disproporionately long time in these apps, and then you see why -- in addition to the Albums and Shared Albums you created, there are numerous albums named by a date, like September 16, 2019, with a couple photos in each.  They all come in alphabetical order in that UI and that clogs the list, it's very sluggish to scroll.  You have to pick your album from the noise and since scrolling is sluggish and jerky it could take a long time.

I've not created those albums.  They are not showing in the Photos app.  Perhaps some app created it at some point?  How do I find an app with the UI to see and delete those albums?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the App(s), not with iOS.  Have you checked the dev’s support site to see if they auto create albums based on date or other such criteria?

Comment: It feels like they are using the same UI and experience the same problem.  BlueSky was the second after Concur that are completely different and unrelated apps.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out there was a folder `iPhoto Events` with 240 albums by day from 2014 and 2015 when it was automatically adding those.  Removing them sped up the apps.